# How do I track users(clients) in a REST GET calls

Tags: rest, get

We have a Public REST application which has a lot of GET's from the clients . We have a way to track the POST calls but we do not have a way to track where the user has come for the GET calls .

Our intention is to have some client specific business rules if we are able to decide where the call has come from ?

Comment: I don't see why GETs have to be different than POSTs. Stick your tracking id in the query string and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: In the POST , they have the tracking ID as a part of their request (headers) but since I cant do that in a GET , I was wondering is I can avoid having the id in the query string

Answer (score 1):

Returning different responses to a GET based on where the request comes from is not a great idea.  Could you not POST the tracking id to an endpoint and have it redirect to a GET of ResourceA for this client and ResourceB for another client.

If you only want to track the GET requests then you could use cookies to identify the client.  However, I would not recommended using the cookies to drive business logic.